# Why do I get a CORS internal server error when trying to do a DELETE request via AWS API Gateway and Lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I made todo application, i could process GET,POST method in lambda function but i got error when invoke delete method.Here i want to delete data in dynamo db by making delete query from axios through lambda function

This is axios delete function,it send `{"data": {"id":this.id}}` to lambda

```
   axios.delete('https://94sc9th9bi.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/item',
        { "data": {"id":this.id}}).then(
          res => {
            console.log(res.data.id)
          }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})

      this.getalltask()
    },
```

I have lambda api for delete

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event)
    let body = JSON.parse(event.body);
     const scanItemPayload = {
        TableName: 'aws-training',
        Key:{
         id: body.data.id
    }
     }
     console.log(body);

   
    const dynamoDBResponse = await docClient.delete(scanItemPayload).promise()
  console.log(dynamoDBResponse)

    const response = {
        body: JSON.stringify(dynamoDBResponse),
       statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
 
  },
    };
    return response;
};
```

i test lambda above with

```
{
    "body": "{\"data\":{\"id\":\"1633613467228\"}}"
}
```

and i got statusCode 200  and no error and i check that the data is deleted in dynamo db

i have a DELETE method API that is related to the lambda function above, and i test delete method api above by giving query {item} => id=1633613467228 , this is the id  i want to delete

but it gave me result

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}


with error log

Execution log for request f83e7e01-52ca-498d-b3e6-34d972510ad8
Fri Oct 08 15:50:00 UTC 2021 : Starting execution for request: f83e7e01-52ca-498d-b3e6-34d972510ad8
Fri Oct 08 15:50:00 UTC 2021 : HTTP Method: DELETE, Resource Path: /item
Fri Oct 08 15:50:00 UTC 2021 : Method request path: {}
Fri Oct 08 15:50:00 UTC 2021 : Method request query string: {id=1633613467228}
Fri Oct 08 15:50:00 UTC 2021 : Method request headers: {}
Fri Oct 08 15:50:00 UTC 2021 : Method request body before transformations: 
Fri Oct 08 15:50:00 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:184371581740:function:aws-training-20211006-p-delete/invocations
```

and  i test with postman

```
https://94sc9th9bi.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/item?id=1633613467228
```

i got error, it seem that the query ?id=1633613467228 is not work

i also test the application , i got CORRS/network error in console although i already set access control orign to *

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://94sc9th9bi.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/item?' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
index.vue?0f48:64 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:117)
xhr.js?b50d:210 DELETE https://94sc9th9bi.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/item? net::ERR_FAILED 502
```

so my questions are: 
1.why delete method in api above result in internal server error and how can i test the method. i also got confused of the different between test in api gateway and test in lambda function. Is my test data wrong format?

2. in axios i have `"data": {"id":this.id}})`  , is
   `Key:{id: body.data.id}` right way to get the data send by axios in aws lambda function?

this is the eror from amazon cloudwatch. it seems 'data' is null.

```
START RequestId: 8197a2bb-b045-438b-8b37-4467687006e3 Version: $LATEST
2021-10-09T06:28:31.894Z    8197a2bb-b045-438b-8b37-4467687006e3    INFO    { key: { id: '1633613467228' } }
2021-10-09T06:28:31.927Z    8197a2bb-b045-438b-8b37-4467687006e3    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "SyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
    "stack": [
        "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
        "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:12:21)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}

END RequestId: 8197a2bb-b045-438b-8b37-4467687006e3
REPORT RequestId: 8197a2bb-b045-438b-8b37-4467687006e3  Duration: 56.29 ms  Billed Duration: 57 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 72 MB  Init Duration: 399.98 ms    
START RequestId: ff096041-a1fb-4349-abbc-a5d422e034d6 Version: $LATEST
2021-10-09T06:29:04.648Z    ff096041-a1fb-4349-abbc-a5d422e034d6    INFO    {
  resource: '/item',
  path: '/item',
  httpMethod: 'DELETE',
  headers: null,
  multiValueHeaders: null,
  queryStringParameters: { id: '1633613467228' },
  multiValueQueryStringParameters: { id: [ '1633613467228' ] },
  pathParameters: null,
  stageVariables: null,
  requestContext: {
    resourceId: '2gw7om',
    resourcePath: '/item',
    httpMethod: 'DELETE',
    extendedRequestId: 'G7V7mFskNjMF-vg=',
    requestTime: '09/Oct/2021:06:29:04 +0000',
    path: '/item',
    accountId: '184371581740',
    protocol: 'HTTP/1.1',
    stage: 'test-invoke-stage',
    domainPrefix: 'testPrefix',
    requestTimeEpoch: 1633760944483,
    requestId: 'f7596258-871a-4b15-b62c-11d434e176b4',
    identity: {
      cognitoIdentityPoolId: null,
      cognitoIdentityId: null,
      apiKey: 'test-invoke-api-key',
      principalOrgId: null,
      cognitoAuthenticationType: null,
      userArn: 'arn:aws:iam::184371581740:user/user07',
      apiKeyId: 'test-invoke-api-key-id',
      userAgent: 'aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.12.71 Linux/5.4.134-73.228.amzn2int.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.302-b08 java/1.8.0_302 vendor/Oracle_Corporation cfg/retry-mode/standard',
      accountId: '184371581740',
      caller: 'AIDASV3LHCMWIZKMZMLPE',
      sourceIp: 'test-invoke-source-ip',
      accessKey: 'ASIASV3LHCMWBJROEHQN',
      cognitoAuthenticationProvider: null,
      user: 'AIDASV3LHCMWIZKMZMLPE'
    },
    domainName: 'testPrefix.testDomainName',
    apiId: '94sc9th9bi'
  },
  body: null,
  isBase64Encoded: false
}
2021-10-09T06:29:04.667Z    ff096041-a1fb-4349-abbc-a5d422e034d6    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'data' of null",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:16:19)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}

END RequestId: ff096041-a1fb-4349-abbc-a5d422e034d6
REPORT RequestId: ff096041-a1fb-4349-abbc-a5d422e034d6  Duration: 180.66 ms Billed Duration: 181 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB  
START RequestId: 1adde91a-ce53-4d2f-8fa8-d296352fc689 Version: $LATEST
2021-10-09T06:30:01.788Z    1adde91a-ce53-4d2f-8fa8-d296352fc689    INFO    { key: { id: '1633613467228' } }
2021-10-09T06:30:01.807Z    1adde91a-ce53-4d2f-8fa8-d296352fc689    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "SyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
    "stack": [
        "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
        "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:12:21)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

[intecept axios to see data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snEQ8.png)

i test lambda function with body  and got 200 
[test lambda with body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Zdk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JoJN.png)

i test api gateway by add query for delete it gave internal server error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auFez.png)

i tried to make request by using axios here, i want to delete task which name is 'aa' with id = 1633601975370 
[delete task name="aa"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T7xn.png)

as you can see, body with id is sent, but there is error when axios request delete api

error i got in console 
[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gTXg.png)

amaxon cloudwatch log error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyciS.png)

[cloudwatch log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptWr6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I got a CORS error the in console even though I've already set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`

The question is:

**Are you trying to enable CORS for a Lambda *proxy* integration or a Lambda *non-proxy* integration?**

Enabling CORS will *differ* based on the integration type.

---

First, refer to the [*Enable CORS on a resource using the API Gateway console*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) section of the Amazon API Gateway developer guide as it includes images etc.

**Follow the guide for proxy & non-proxy.**

If it is a **non-proxy integration**, you're done.

---

**If it's a proxy integration** (which I don't think it is), your request will still fail - a `DELETE` request is classed as a *complex request* by the CORS specification.

This means that if you are making a call to this endpoint using a web app, you may have allowed all *origins* but you haven't specified which HTTP *methods* to allow (which the web app will request for in the form of a `preflight` request before the `DELETE` request).

So you'll need to also set the [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) header to `*` to allow HTTP `DELETE`in the response returned by your Lambda:

```
const response = {
    body: JSON.stringify(dynamoDBResponse),
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i used lambda integration with proxy and i also enabled the corrs option in apigateway but still got internal server error

Comment: They must be enabled separately, not at the same time - can you please paste images of how your API endpoint is set up? Stick with either proxy or non-proxy & let me know the error.

Comment: Is it still “blocked by CORS policy”, or are headers being returned now?

Comment: i added picture of the api gateway and lambda. i also added error from cloudwatch log , it said 'data' is null , is this related to this? in lambda function resource based policy i changed policy statement source policy to arn:aws:execute-api:ffffff:xxxx:api-id/*/*

Comment: i dont understand, how can i read id from query string? is my lambda function wrong?  body is empty because i cant debug data from axios, i added screenshot when i sent axios delete request.

Comment: @defs Okay - **show me the CloudWatch logs, API gateway configuration & full HTTP error returned for when you send data in the body via Axios & delete any other images or info other than the above**

Comment: i added picture when i test lambda function, it returned 200. but when i test delete from api gateway with query `id= '1633613467228'`  i got internal server error. i mean i have to make sure this work right before i send request from axios

Comment: Yes you did but the error was about missing origin header - do you still get the same error? Your error now is the body being null, not the header not being returned from what I'm seeing - what is the error after fixing CORS?

Comment: @defs In `but it gave me result...`, you're passing it as a query string parameter not in the body - you question is a mix of everything & I'm confused to what error you're getting. Apply CORS as in my answer above and if you no longer get `'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` your question has been answered.

Comment: i edit my question and added picture when i make request from axios above. as you can see, axios sent body with id , but when it try to access the api , i still got network error corrs, and delete api error

Comment: Do you have an `OPTIONS` method in the UI as well as making the code return the relevant headers? You need to follow the guide linked above for *proxy integrations as well*

Comment: im sorry i can see the log error on amazon cloudwatch. i added amazon cloudwatch log picture

Comment: @defs OK great, your CORS issue is fixed - the error you've linked is because you're sending `body: '{"id":"3242342344"}'` while the code is reading `id: body.data.id`. Change your code to `id: body.id` to make it work (or encapsulate ID in a data object if you need to)

Comment: Thanks it seems work! i want to know why id:body.id? and when i test lambda function with  `{"body": "{\"data\":{\"id\":\"1633613467228\"}}"} `why it produce error  "ValidationException", not match with schma ? and also why i cant test the api gateway with query string id=1633613477228 ? i still got internal server error. i just want to know how to test api this from amazon console. thankyou for your help!!

Comment: @defs No worries! '{"id":"3242342344"}' will give you an `id` object, while `body.data.id` is looking for `id` *inside* a data object - since you don't have a data object, it will fail -  you can test API gateway with a query string but you're looking for where you can specify the body so a bit further down the page, you can specify the body contents and that'll work with your Lambda

Comment: thanks!! So it isnt possible to work with query string and for this kind approach it isnt possible to debug through amazon console? i mean if i want to use query string i have to change axios request parameter? the only way to debug is to see the amazon cloudwatch?

Comment: @defs It is possible yes but you need to change your Axios request URL to include the `?id=000000` and then change your Lambda code to use `event.queryStringParameters.id` & not `body.Id` - CloudWatch is just for logs, the API Gateway test view allows you to use query string parameters or the body, both are possible

Comment: Thankyou i understand now!! but i want to know why lambda functions work from its own test but when trigger from api gateway it produced internal server error? i tried to uncheck integration proxy and test from api gateway , and test through delete method test it works and produced 200, but when i send request from axios , it wont work. why this application need integration proxy?

Comment: It doesn't need it - there are just different configurations depending on if you use it or not. Not sure if I understand the first bit of the question however sorry!

Comment: Thanks, this only works when I enabled integration proxy. When I uncheck integration proxy, i got corrs error for delete method like in the picture i updated before. Although i  already enabled corrs from console and added allow-access-control origin , method, and method in lambda function. When i test API corrs configuration, such as tried to `curl -v https://94sc9th9bi.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/item` , you can see there is no allow-access-control-headers in the response. is this because wrong configuration?

Comment: Yes, your integration *response* (on the 2nd row on your API gateway method) needs to be set to allow the headers through - read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html

Comment: do you mean to change mapping value of allow access control origin of response header in header mappings ? try to put ` headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    }` in mapping template but still no avail.

Comment: `{ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true }`